# Re-indent lisp code when new code is added in emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp

Say I have this:

```
 (defun foo ()
   (format t "hello there"))
```

Then I realize I left out the critically important part of the algorithm, and I add it here:

```
 (defun foo ()
   (let ((x 0))
   (format t "hello there")))
```

As you can see, emacs properly indents new code, but lines that are already there are not automatically updated to reflect where their indentation should be in relation to other lines of code added later.

Is there a way to force an update of the indentations?

Comment: [`indent-sexp`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_277.html) maybe?

Comment: @tripleee i received the magic answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case: C-M-a to move to `defun`, C-M-q to indent the function.

Comment: beautiful!! just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already it may also be wroth checking out [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit). It takes some getting use to (I felt like i was fighting it for the first few days) but it makes it feel much more like you are working with structure rather than text.

For me I just mark the code and hit tab and it all indents correctly. I'm not sure if this is a paredit thing though or just standard emacs behaviour.

Comment: I don't have paredit installed but I tried your mark text and tab trick and it works fine, thanks, useful!